# Can't create new array foreach record in index collection laravel

Tags: arrays, laravel, foreach

I have an index of customers that displays a summary of their purchases.

I need to show a cross in the acceptance column if any of their purchases have not been agreed to.  To do that I was going to make an array of acceptances for each customer and check for null using in_array()

However I can't get an array to be created for each customer it just keeps one acceptance array and adding values to it from both customers.

**Customer Controller (index)**

```
$customers = Customer::with('paymentplans')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
```

**Customers Index**

```
foreach($customers as $customer){
        foreach($customer->paymentplan as $plan){
             $acceptance[] = $plan->accepted;
             }
}
```

This will output the following array:

```
array:7 [▼
0 => null
1 => 1
2 => 1
3 => 1
4 => 1
5 => 1
6 => 1
]
```

**I need something like this for my two customers**

```
array:5 [▼
  0 => null
  1 => 1
  2 => 1
  3 => 1
  4 => 1
  ]
array:2 [▼
  0 => 1
  1 => 1
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

foreach($customers as $customer){

```
foreach($customer->paymentplan as $plan){
     $acceptance[$customer->id][] = $plan->accepted;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($customers as $customer){
    foreach($customer->paymentplan as $plan){
         $acceptance[$customer->id] = $plan->accepted;
    }
}
```